# Automatically upload a file from Windows machine to Linux server?

Tags: java, linux, file-upload

I have a web application which process the data collected from different client machines (1000-1500 client machines) and shows the results in graphical format.

The client machine generates an Excel sheet periodically and this excel sheet needs to be transfered to the server after every 30 minutes.

I want your help to identify the right approach to write this client component (Windows) which will generate and upload the excel sheet automatically after a specified time duration. I would also like help identifying the right approach for the server component which will recieve and save the data uploaded by clients.

Should we use an FTP-like implementation for the server side component?

Comment: What happens to the old spreadsheet from the client after 30 minutes? Is it overwritten, or is this a cumulative thing where all the old ones are kept on the server? If it's a cumulative thing, is this a problem area, or do you have something worked out for looking at older versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a web application then using the HTTP protocol would be easier because you can (presumably) easily create a new request handler to accept the file.

Create a new route which accepts POST requests to a URI and takes the request body as the Excel spreadsheet.  The handler for this route will handle the storage and processing of the file.  The client needs only to know the correct route and to properly submit the HTTP request.

FTP is a somewhat antiquated protocol due to better security and library support for newer ones such as SCP/SFTP and HTTP.